# I want to change MySQL data to JSON file but get 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_json' referenced before assignment'

Tags: python, json, variables, syntax-error, return-value

```py
list_user = [{'id': 'c9b54584-e70b-11ec-b5e5-02c9dcd6ed1e', 'name': 'Asif', 'age': 25, 'weight': 68, 'height': 170, 'bmi': Decimal('23.53'), 'report': 'Normal'}, {'id': 'c9b571be-e70b-11ec-b5e5-02c9dcd6ed1e', 'name': 'Ema', 'age': 24, 'weight': 52, 'height': 166, 'bmi': Decimal('23.53'), 'report': 'Normal'}]

def func_write_JSON(list_user):  
    while True: 
        filename = input ('please name your file :')
        filename_txt = ('.\output\{}.json'.format(filename))
        try:
            mydict = create_dict()
            for row in listUser:
                mydict.add(row[0],{"name":row[1],"age":row[2],"weight":row[3],"height":row[4],"bmi":str(row[5]),"report":row[6]})
            user_json = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
            with open(filename_txt, 'w') as f:
                f.write(user_json)
           
        except Exception as e:            
            print (e)

        else:
            break

        finally:
            print (user_json)
            return user_json
```

Comment: class create_dict(dict): 
     
    def __init__(self): 
        self = dict() 
  
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self[key] = value

Comment: btw this the class and function to add key:value

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the program fails in performing the *add* within the for loop, therefore you actually never store anything in *user_json*. In fact, if you want to access the *id* of your user, you should write *row['id']* rather than row[0]. Clearly, this is the same for each value of the dictionary.

An other small mistake is that you are using *listUser* within the mentioned loop, while the variable in *func_write_JSON* is called *list_user* instead.

Please, consider the following code to fix your issues:

```
def func_write_JSON(list_user):  
    while True: 
        filename = input ('please name your file :')
        filename_txt = ('.\output\{}.json'.format(filename))
        try:
            mydict = create_dict()
            for row in list_user:
                mydict.add(row['id'],{"name":row['name'],"age":row['age'],"weight":row['weight'],"height":row['height'],"bmi":str(row['bmi']),"report":row['report']})
            user_json = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
            with open(filename_txt, 'w') as f:
                f.write(user_json)
        
        except Exception as e:     
            print (e)

        else:
            break

        finally:
            print (user_json)
            return user_json
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: it helps. thanks you so much. May I know why the 'add' do not accept row[0] and accept row['id']?

Comment: Yes, of course. A dictionary is not a list (in which instead you can use row[0]), so you don't access the value by position, but you exploit the key:value pair. Therefore, for your 'add' method row[0] has no meaning since you are not correctly accessing the dictionary information. You could also transform the dictionary to access it by position, but it would be inconvenient.